# Forcing jQueryUI sortable 'li' on same line as a 'div'

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui

This should be simple yet I can't figure out how to force a group of `li` elements onto the same line as a `div`.

I've considered many answers here that recommend using `span`, `inline-block`, a wrapper, avoiding `float`, etc. but none seem to work.

Here's a fiddle describing the issue: [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sc28/1oj4188d/19/)

And the HTML I've tried:

```
  <div id="synthesize_div" class="float_center main-div" style="width:1300px; box-sizing:border-box;">
    <span id="decision-text" class="secondary_text">Text</span>
    <p></p>
    <div id="column1" class="" style="color:blue;">hello</div>
    <ul id="columns">
      <li id="compared1" class="secondary_text">+</li>
      <li id="compared2" class="secondary_text">+</li>
      <li id="compared3" class="secondary_text">+</li>
      <li id="compared4" class="secondary_text">+</li>
      <li id="compared5" class="secondary_text">+</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
```

Is there perhaps some conflict with jQuery-UI or is there a simple solution I'm missing?

Comment: It is not clear what steps need to be taken to replicate the issue. also to comment out CSS, you need to use `/* ... */` not `//`. Please clarify the issue further.

Comment: Seems to work to sort the items: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/qd6yrkye/

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I thought the `//` worked as well!     I added some text in the elements to better emphasize the issue: how can the list elements not break to a new line, but stay on the same as the div?  In other words, what is causing the list elements to start on a new line? [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sc28/qd6yrkye/4/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your

```
<div id="column1" ...
```

is a block element, because divs are block elements by default.  You need to modify that if you want inline elements to be inline with it.  A simple

```
display: inline-block;
```

on that div works while maintaining the size and other formatting you already have set up; you could put that in the style tag or in your CSS.

You'll need to set your `<ul>` to display:inline as well.

Comment: Thank you so much!  The trick was indeed to also setting the `<ul>` to inline, because actually the `div` was already set to `inline-block`...  Here's the working [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sc28/qd6yrkye/12/)